# windows cmd enabledelayedexpansion not working

Tags: windows, cmd

I'm having trouble running !var! examples ad described here http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html

Instead of the expected variable content output as the example describes, I get the literal "bang V A R bang" output, any idea?

```
C:\>Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
C:\>Set _var=first
C:\>Set _var=second& Echo %_var% !_var!
first !_var!
```

thanks.

Comment: To get delayed expansion in the command prompt, run `cmd /v:on`. Here's a command to set this permanently for the current user: `reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v DelayedExpansion /t REG_DWORD /d 1`.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting an unexpected result because you are issuing the commands at the command prompt. Create a batch file by putting the following commands in a file with a .bat extension then run the batch file.

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set _var=first
Set _var=second& Echo %_var% !_var!
```

E.g., if I created a batch file named delayedexp.bat with the above contents, I would see the following when I run it:

```
C:\Users\JDoe\Documents\>delayedexp
first second
```

Answer (score 1):

`setlocal` only works within the confines of a command script:

```
help setlocal
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the parameters of the cmd call, you can set parameter /v. Must be first. And use ! instead % for variables.

```
%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /v /c set a=10&echo a=!a!&echo My Path is %CD%&pause
```

This is how, for example, you can get the date in the Russia-France format directly in the Windows shortcut, where a simple percentage is impossible due to its doubling. In std queries with the /v parameter, both a percentage and an exclamation mark will work fine, but single % for cicles.

```
%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /v /c echo off&for /F "tokens=1-6 delims=:., " %A In ("!date! !time!") Do (Echo %A.%B.%C %D:%E:%F)&pause
```